# Error when trying to build the 'opencv_contrib' using cmake-gui

Tags: opencv, cmake-gui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv5UE.png)1. I have downloaded and extracted the 'opencv_contrib-master' & 'opencv-master' from Git repo.
2. cmake 3.9 version is installed.

When I run the cmake, I am getting the below error: [image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10. Any help?

This is a screnshot of the CMAkeDownloadLog.txt
[ErrorLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylw5w.png)

From ErrorLog:

```
#use_cache "C:/Downloads/OPENCV/opencv-master/.cache"
#do_copy "opencv_ffmpeg.dll" "b8120c07962d591e2e9071a1bf566fd0" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/0a0e88972a7ea97708378d0488a65f83e7cc5e69/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg.dll" "C:/OpenCV/3rdparty/ffmpeg"
#missing "C:/OpenCV/3rdparty/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg.dll"
#check_md5 "C:/Downloads/OPENCV/opencv-master/.cache/ffmpeg/b8120c07962d591e2e9071a1bf566fd0-opencv_ffmpeg.dll"
#mismatch_md5 "C:/Downloads/OPENCV/opencv-master/.cache/ffmpeg/b8120c07962d591e2e9071a1bf566fd0-opencv_ffmpeg.dll" "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
#delete "C:/Downloads/OPENCV/opencv-master/.cache/ffmpeg/b8120c07962d591e2e9071a1bf566fd0-opencv_ffmpeg.dll"
#cmake_download "C:/Downloads/OPENCV/opencv-master/.cache/ffmpeg/b8120c07962d591e2e9071a1bf566fd0-opencv_ffmpeg.dll" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/0a0e88972a7ea97708378d0488a65f83e7cc5e69/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg.dll"
# timeout on name lookup is not supported
#   Trying 151.101.112.133...
# TCP_NODELAY set
# connect to 151.101.112.133 port 443 failed: Timed out
# Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Timed out
# Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Don't post a link to an image, post actual text, also the screenshot you've posted just shows warnings, not an error

Comment: The error log is pretty big. If i copy paste the content here, it will be too lengthy

Comment: Well you've failed to show any error, so currently your question is unanswerable

Comment: CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:193 (message):
  FFMPEG: Download failed: 7;"Couldn't connect to server"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  C:/OpenCV/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:20 (ocv_download)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:228 (download_win_ffmpeg)
  CMakeLists.txt:634 (include)

Answer (score 3):

As you probably noticed, CMake cannot connect to the server providing the file it needs to download. Most likely that is some problem with your network connection.

For me CMake didn't know about the company https proxy. CMake knows about this through the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. If this is your problem, you can set these variables for your system. If you cannot set environment variables system wide or you just want a quick test, start up command prompt and run

```
set HTTP_PROXY=<your-proxy-here>
set HTTPS_PROXY=<your-proxy-here>
c:\program files\cmake\bin\cmake-gui.exe
```

The path to cmake may be different, if it was installed to a different location.

If this is not the cause, something else is blocking your connection. E. g. a firewall, malware protection, etc.